# cleartool error: "cannot command from stream for non-UCM view" or "view is not attached to a UCM stream"

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have this view restored from back up and it is re-registered and retagged. I can set to the view but there is not stream attached to it. when I do catcs, it contains the stream name and OID. when I describe the view it says UCM view. Is there any way to make this view attach to the stream?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, as illustrated by [that identical question on IBM forums](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014159367):

> There's currently no mechanism to reattach views to streams.
>   **UCM views are connected to streams via a particular kind of internal PVOB object; perhaps your view and PVOB have become out of sync as a result of inconsistent backup restoration**.

One concern was about old UMC activities, but:

> As long as you can checkin any checkouts in the view and copy out any view-private files you wish to keep, it's safe to remove the view and create a new one on the stream.
>   **You won't lose any activities since activities are attached to the stream, not the view**.
>
> The only thing you may need to watch out for is if CC thinks the activity is still set in the view, but you're not able to unset it (`cleartool setact -none`).
>   In this case, `cleartool checkvob -ucm -fix` on the activity object after you remove the view should fix it.

So, in short, and after getting from that old view what you need, drop it and create a new one.